# ($) dollar symbol outside brackets in powershell

Tags: powershell, syntax

```
 Does anyone know what $symbol does outside brackets in
 powershell as    in write-host "The file name is $($filename)"
```

And also I have noticed that when I write a function as below

```
function time() 
{write-host "The time is $(get-date)"}
return time
```

AND

```
function time
{ Write-host "the time is (get-date)"}
time
```

The format of the get-date output changes depending on if i placed the $symbol  outside the brackets as in $(get-date) and when I use the (get-date) without any symbols. 
   Does any know know how to search the help file for the meaning of the $ symbol in powershell help command?
Thank-you

Comment: The `(get-date)` format should just output `(get-date)` the string from that function. Does it not?

Comment: get-date gives me Wednesday, April 8, 2015 7:27:57 PM

Comment: but $(get-date) give me a different format : the date is 4/8/2015 7:30:29 PM

Comment: That's a very different question then you asked here or that you implied for that. That's actually a reasonable question to ask on its own I think.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a "subexpression", and it's covered (albeit very briefly) in

```
get-help about_operators
```

Also from [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx)